# Переопределить Value в ModelChoiceField. Django

Tags: python, django, select

```
serviceForModal=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Services.objects.all(), required=False)
```

Который генерирует вот такой select

```
<option value="6">nikita123</option>
```

Мне нужно, чтобы ModelChoiceField генерировал value используя текст, в данном случае "nikia123", а не id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Придётся вместо `ModelChoiceField` использовать `ChoiceField`:

```
CHOICES = ((i.some_field, i.some_field) for i in Services.objects.all())
service_for_modal = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, required=False)
```

Только надо быть готовым к тому, что после валидации формы, в поле будет не экземпляр модели, а текст из атрибута `value` выбранного `option`.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать `to_field_name`.

```
field2 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=..., to_field_name="name")
```

Вернет:

```
<select id="id_field2" name="field2">
<option value="obj1.name">Object1</option>
<option value="obj2.name">Object2</option>
...
</select>
```

Подробнее [в документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield).